# Limit a size of an add on in a website. Html

Tags: html

So I link twitter to my website. However, I cannot limit the size of the wigget. I want it to be a size of 300px by 300px. I tried to do `iframe width = "300" height = "300"` but it doesn't work. I want the decrease the size of the twitter wigget. How do I do it? I am trying to make https://i.stack.imgur.com/h90nz.jpg looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emd6s.jpg.

The html code is posted below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

    <!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

        <title>

    MogoTXT is a fun, easy to use celebrity-entertainment platform that allows fans to follow their favorite celebs, read and hear what they are saying, and see what they are doing!

        </title>


        <!-- Included CSS Files (Uncompressed) -->
        <!--
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/foundation.min.css">
            -->

        <!-- Included CSS Files (Compressed) -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/foundationv0000004.css">
        <link href="stylesheets/wb-main0000007.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <script src="javascripts/modernizr.foundation.js"> </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-18132180-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>
        <!-- IE Fix for HTML5 Tags -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"> </script>
        <![endif]-->


    <meta property="og:description" content="MogoTXT is a fun, easy to use celebrity-entertainment platform that allows fans to follow their favorite celebs, read and hear what they are saying, and see what they are doing!" />
    <meta        name="Description" content="MogoTXT is a fun, easy to use celebrity-entertainment platform that allows fans to follow their favorite celebs, read and hear what they are saying, and see what they are doing!" />
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=602297014" />


    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Header and Nav -->
        <div id="logonav">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="four columns">
                    <h1><a href="http://www.mogotxt.com/"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="With Buddies" width="157" height="53" /></a></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="eight columns">
                    <ul class="nav-bar right">
                        <li class="has-flyout" id="games-nav"><a>Games</a>
                            <a href="#" class="flyout-toggle"><span> </span></a>
                            <ul class="flyout">
                                <li><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/app/big-fly-baseball/id602297014?mt=8" target="_blank">Big Fly Baseball<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://mogoball.com/" class="flyout-toggle" target="_blank">MogoBall<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/mogohoops" target="_blank" class="flyout-toggle">Mogo Hoops<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>
                                <!--<li><a href="http://www.mogotxt.com/BubbleGalaxy">Bubble Galaxy With Buddies<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>-->
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://mogotxt.com/stores" id="support-nav" target="_blank">Shop</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="mobilenav">
            <nav class="clearfix">
              <ul class="nav-bar right clearfix">
                    <li><a href="http://www.mogotxt.com/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Big Fly Baseball<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.mogoball.com/">MogoBall<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">Mogo Hoops<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>

                    <!--<li><a href="http://www.mogotxt.com/BubbleGalaxy">Bubble Galaxy With Buddies<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>-->

                    <li><a href="http://mogotxt.com/about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://mogotxt.com/mogocentral">Mogo Central/Athletes</a></li>

                    <li><a href="http://mogotxt.com/faq">Help</a></li>
              </ul>
                <a href="http://www.mogotxt.com/" id="pull"><img src="images/logo.png" width="157" height="53"></a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    <!-- End Header and Nav -->



    <!-- Included JS Files (Compressed) -->
        <script src="javascripts/jquery.js"> </script>
        <script src="javascripts/foundation.min.js"> </script>

    <!-- Initialize JS Plugins -->
        <script src="javascripts/app.js"> </script>
        <script src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.orbit.js"> </script>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    var pull = $('#pull');
                    menu = $('nav ul');
                    menuHeight = menu.height();

                    $(pull).on('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        menu.slideToggle();
                    });

                    $(window).resize(function () {
                        var w = $(window).width();
                        if (w > 720 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                            menu.removeAttr('style');
                        }
                    });
                });
        </script>



    <!-- Featured Region -->.
    <center>
      <img src="images/big-fly-baseball.png" alt="Smiley face" width="940" height="500" />
    </center> 

    <!-- Three-up Content Blocks -->

    <div class="row" id="game-details">
      <div class="eight columns main-content">

        <h3 style='font-size:29px'>About Us:</h3>        
            <ul>
                <p>MogoTXT is a San Francisco based game development studio that wants to bring back the fun and excitement of early sports games. The sports games industry has become stale and we want to change that by starting from scratch and making games that people can enjoy over and over again with their friends and other gamers. </p>
                <p>We are building awesome sports games for iOS, Android, Facebook, and Micro-Consoles!</p>
                <p>We build games for you to enjoy, so let us know what you want to see and play by emailing us at info@mogotxt.com</p>
            </ul>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
      </div>
       <div align="right">
      <iframe width="300" height="180"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JLZ1_0icv1k">
</iframe>




    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/gridironthunder" data-widget-id="369622317229301760">Tweets by @gridironthunder</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>



</div> 

</div>

<div class="row" id="tweet-details">



</div>

    </div>

    <div class="row" id="our-games"><img src="images/sat.png" alt="Smiley face" width="650" height="300" />
      <div class="four columns mini-mogo-hoops"></div>
        <div class="four columns mini-bubble-galaxy">

        </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
                $('#screenshots').orbit({
                    animation: 'fade',
                    fluid: true,
                    timer: true,
                    resetTimerOnClick: false,
                    advanceSpeed: 5000,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    startClockOnMouseOut: true,
                    startClockOnMouseOutAfter: 0,
                    directionalNav: true,
                    bullets: false,
                });

            });
        </script>


    </div>


    <script src="http://www.mogotxt.com/Scripts/jquery.fitvids.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">        $(document).ready(function () { $('.fitvid').fitVids(); }); </script>








        <div class="drop-shadow lifted">     
            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer class="row">
                <div class="twelve columns">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="four columns" id="footerlogo">
                            <h1><a href="http://www.mogotxt.com/"><img src="images/Mogo_logo.png" alt="With Buddies" width="405" height="136" /></a></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns sitemap">
                            <ul class="link-list left">
                                <li class="header">Games</li>
                                <li><li><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/app/big-fly-baseball/id602297014?mt=8" target="_blank">Big Fly Baseball<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://mogoball.com/" target="_blank">MogoBall<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/mogohoops">Mogo Hoops<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>
                                <!--<li><a href="http://www.mogotxt.com/BubbleGalaxy">Bubble Galaxy With Buddies<sup>&trade;</sup></a></li>-->
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="two columns sitemap">
                            <ul class="link-list left">
                              <li class="header"></li>                          
                            <li class="header"></li></ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="two columns sitemap">
                            <ul class="link-list left">
                            <li class="header"><a href="http://mogotxt.com/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                                <li class="header support"><a href="http://mogotxt.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</li>
                                <li class="header support"><a href="http://mogotxt.com/terms">Terms of Service</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="twelve columns">
                    <div class="row" id="pp-tos">
                        <div class="six columns sitemap"></div>
                        <div class="six columns sitemap">
                            <ul class="link-list left">
                                <li></li>    
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="link-list right">
                                <li></li>    
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--<div class="six columns sitemap">

                        </div>-->
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </footer>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried using? We don't know what your code *actually* is

Comment: ^It's really messy and I don't know if anyone would want to look at my code and try to figure out what's happen but okay.

Comment: How about only posting a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (aka only include the least amount of code that reproduces the issue)

Answer (score 0):

You should edit in CSS via Id or class,or  put this in your iframe tag:

```
 style="position:absolute;width:300px;height:300px;"
```